# How to draw the arcs in the following figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
    \usepackage{pst-all}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}

\tikzset{every path/.style=thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
        thick,
         inner sep=1pt,
         minimum size=.13cm
       },
       curvy line/.style={decorate,,rounded corners=2pt,decoration={random steps,segment length=3mm,
       amplitude=1mm}}}
\tikzset{curvy line/.style={decorate,decoration={snake,segment length=8.5mm,
   amplitude=1mm}}}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\begin{center}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7,every label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]
\begin{scope}   

      \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:{$x$}]{};   

      \node (a2) at (1.5,0) [acteur,label=below:{$x'$}]{};
      \node (a3) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=left:{}]{};
      \node (a9) at (0,1.5) [acteur,label=left:{}]{};
      \node (a7) at (.75,3) [acteur,label=right:{}]{};

      \draw  (a1) -- (a2);
      \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3);

      \draw  [dashed](a3) -- (a7);

      \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a9);
      \draw [dashed] (a9) -- (a7);
      % \draw (3,1.5) circle (.8);
      % \draw (.75, 4.6) circle (.8);
      % \draw (-1.5, 1.5) circle (.8);
      \draw (1.5,1.5) -- (2.7,1.5);
      \draw [dashed] (1.5,1.5) -- (2.7,1.1);
      \draw [dashed] (1.5,1.5) -- (2.7,1.8);
      \draw [dashed] (.75,3) -- (.99,4.2);
      \draw [dashed] (.75,3) -- (.50,4.2);
      \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (-1.12,1.8);
      \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (-1.12,1.2);
      % \draw [dotted](1.85,.5) to[bend left=100] (1.85,2.5);
      % \draw (2.5,2.5) arc (0:315:1.75cm and 1cm);
      % \draw[dashed] (1.5,1.5)[bend left=90] arc (0:180:1.5cm);

      \draw (.75,3) -- (.75,4.2);
      \draw (0,1.5)-- (-1.1,1.5);
      \node at (.75,-1) {$U_1$}; 
      \node at (-1.6,1.5) {\scriptsize{$T_1$}}; 
      \node at (0.75,4.8) {\scriptsize{$T_2$}}; 
      \node at (3.3,1.5) {\scriptsize{$T_3$}}; 

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\caption{The solid edge in $U_1$ denotes the matching edge. The graph $U_1$ lies in $\mathcal{U}_1$ while $U_2$ lies in 
$\mathcal{U}_2$. }
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How to draw the arc curves in the figure. Give an idea.

Comment: Please consider accepting answers to earlier questions you got. Otherwise users may hesitate to answer this. You keep using e.g. the answer that provided you with `curvy lines`, why don't you just accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 12mm,
     acteur/.style = {circle, draw, fill=black,
                      minimum size=1.5mm, node contents={}
                      },
every label/.style = {font=\footnotesize},
 every path/.style = thick,
        bend angle = 15
                        ]
% nodes
\node (a1)  [acteur,label=below:$x$];
\node (a2)  [acteur, above=of a1];
\node (a3)  [acteur, above right=of a2];
\node (a4)  [acteur, below right=of a3];
\node (a5)  [acteur, below=of a4,label=below:{$x'$}];
% lines
\draw [dashed]  (a1) -- (a2) -- (a3) -- (a4) -- (a5);
\draw           (a1) -- node[below=5mm] {$U_1$} (a5);
% lines at T_1
\draw (a2) -- ++ (-1,0) node[left] {$T_1$};
\draw[dashed] (a2) to[bend  left] ++ (-1,-0.5)
              (a2) to[bend right] ++ (-1, 0.5);     
% lines at T_2
\draw (a3) -- ++ (0,1) node[above] {$T_2$};
\draw[dashed] (a3) to[bend  left] ++ (-0.5,1)
              (a3) to[bend right] ++ ( 0.5,1);
% lines at T_3
\draw (a4) -- ++ (1,0) node[right] {$T_3$};
\draw[dashed] (a4) to[bend  left] ++ (1, 0.5)
              (a4) to[bend right] ++ (1,-0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```